# Why is the Bluetooth symbol in the Bluetooth tag black?

Tags: discussion, tags, sponsored-tags

When you tag a question with [bluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bluetooth) you can see a black Bluetooth logo. Why isn't it blue? Is this intended?

Comment: Good question. FWIW, no, this is not in violation of their trademark guidelines.

Comment: A tag sponsor can have an icon as they see fit. I'm going to guess it's black because having a pale-ish blue on a pale bluey-grey looks rubbish...

Comment: @Jon Clements: The Bluetooth logo isn't pale-ish blue...

Comment: I'm a puppy - I don't do colours well :) Although, taking the logo [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bluetooth) (which may not be pale-ish per se, but definitely isn't dark), setting the background to the tag background colour and shrinking it to the size of the tag icon doesn't look fantastic...

Comment: Quote: ["we moved our moderators to Stack Overflow"](https://www.bluetooth.com/develop-with-bluetooth/developer-resources-tools/developer-forum).  Uh-oh, seems not inappropriate to give some back.  It is up to them to decide what the logo should look like.

Comment: Okay, but maybe someone knows what is behind the black colour of the bluetooth logo. Just curious why they didn't choose blue.

Comment: It's not the color that looks bad, it's that they tried to keep their registered trademark glyph on it, even though that's unreadable at 16x16 pixels.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is black because the sponsor provided a black icon. This is *within their own [Brand Guidelines](https://www.bluetooth.com/develop-with-bluetooth/marketing-branding/brand-guide-logos)*. From the linked PDF, page 12, *Bluetooth figure mark color*:

> The figure mark can be reproduced in black, inverted, or in blue.

The same page includes example reproductions in both blue and black.

So, yes, this is almost certainly intended. We can't otherwise know why the black icon was picked over the blue variant, we are not the sponsor, and no matter how hard I try, I still can't read minds.